# Using update in a firebird stored procedure but data not changing

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird

I have the following stored procedure.  I found a bug in my code that had resulted in bad data.  I wrote this procedure to fix the data.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE RESET_DISABLED_COUNT 
returns (
    person integer,
    game integer,
    disabled integer,
    cnt integer)
as
begin
  for select gr.person_id, gr.game_id, gr.disableds
  from game_roster gr
  into :person, :game, :disabled
  do begin
    select count(gr.id)
    from game_roster gr
    where gr.disabled_by_id = :person and gr.game_id = :game
    into cnt;

    if (cnt <> disabled) then begin
        update game_roster gr set gr.disableds = :cnt where (gr.person_id = :person) and (gr.game_id = :game);
    end
  end
end
```

I then run the procedure from IBExpert and commit.  However, when I run a query on the table, it shows that the old data is still there.  What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean with "when I run a query on the table"? Oh, and you probably are missing the `COMMIT` statement after calling the SP, thats the only reason I can imagine why changes arent persisted... assuming that the logic in the SP is right and you actually change anything at all.

Comment: I meant I would then run a query to check some of the rows I knew to hold bad data.  They would still have the bad data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Can **Cnt** and **Disabled** variables contain NULLs? If so, change condition for

```
if (:cnt IS DISTINCT FROM :disabled) then ...
```

2) Make sure that you **commit** transaction after SP run.

3) Make sure that transaction you select data on is not **SNAPSHOT** transaction. If so, commit and reopen it before running SELECT query.

4) Recheck logic of your procedure.

5) Do you run your procedure inside IBExpert's debugger?

Comment: I was running inside IBExpert.  Turns out I didn't have to change anything.  I shut down IBE and restarted.  Lo and behold, the SP then worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# and ado, this snippet will be handy. Works file on Firebird 1.5 the usp UPDATE_stuff was a typical update or insert type of proc you take for granted with MSSQL. This will allow you to use a stored procedure and actually save the data and save weeks of wasted time.
Config.DB4FB.Open is just a nested class that opens a new FbConnection witt a optional connection string, cos if you are using firebird you need all the grief abstracted away:)

```
FbTransaction FTransaction=null;
using (FbConnection conn = Config.DB4FB.Open(ConnectionString))
{
    FbTransactionOptions options = new FbTransactionOptions();
    options.TransactionBehavior = FbTransactionBehavior.NoWait;
    FTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction(options);
    FbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE_stuff";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("KEY", key);
    cmd.Transaction = FTransaction;
    FbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            while (reader.Read()){}
    FTransaction.Commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to return the 4 output variables you set?

If you DONT need the return values, this is the same thing and "should" work

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RESET_DISABLED_COUNT
AS
declare person integer;
declare game integer;
declare disabled integer;
declare cnt integer;

begin
  for select gr.person_id, gr.game_id, gr.disableds
  from game_roster gr
  into :person, :game, :disabled
  do begin 
    select count(gr.id)
    from game_roster gr
    where gr.disabled_by_id = :person and gr.game_id = :game
    into cnt;
    if (cnt <> disabled) then begin
        update game_roster gr set gr.disableds = :cnt where (gr.person_id = :person) and (gr.game_id = :game);
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Having the variables as output parameters is bad style but not a problem here. Your statement "`Each time your select statement puts a value into (one of the return values) it waits for you to retrieve that value BEFORE it goes to the next row`" is kind of misleading as it suggest that execution of the SP stops, which is not the case... I suggest you try to rephrase it.

Comment: I had those as out parameters for testing purposes.  Before I wrote the update line, I had a "suspend" in its place to see if I was getting the data that needed fixing.  When I was satisfied I was getting that data and no more, I replaced the suspend with update.  Yeah, it was bad style, but leftovers.